# Weblogic 12c deploying an exploded War file

Tags: java, weblogic12c

I have created a mini app that has a dependency on Wiremock for mocking out restful services.

The problem that I am experiencing is when I try and use the application, via Weblogic 12c the context path that Wiremock is expecting is not the correct path. This I have proven by attaching a debugger. It changes the path and adds in another folder.

Is there a way during the deployment of the application into Weblogic 12c that when the war is deployed to install at that location and keep the physical or actual path?

Answer (score 0):

add to weblogic.xml `show-archived-real-path-enabled` set to **true**
Deploy the exploded war file, and create a simple Servlet calling `getRealPath()`.